# Ingress to route gRPC calls and http calls

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, grpc, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to write 2 ingress rules for my nginx ingress controller on my microk8s cluter:

- one to route all gRPC calls to a backend (the `api` service). The RPC paths all follow the pattern: `/thing.v1.ThingService/AMethod`, e.g: `/pizzas.v1.PizzasService/ListFlavours`
- one to route the rest of the traffic to the frontend (`fe` service)

This is what I have:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: dev.fancy.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: fe
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.fancy.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod-tls
```

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: fanout-ingress-grpc
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: 'GRPC'
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: dev.fancy.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/.*Service.*"
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: api
            port:
              number: 8080
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev.fancy.com
    secretName: letsencrypt-prod-tls
```

In this configuration, calling `/pizzas.v1.PizzasService/ListFlavours` doesn't work, it returns a 404.

If I use this more specific config in the `fanout-ingress-grpc` rule, everything works:

```yaml
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /pizzas.v1.PizzasService/ListFlavours"
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

So it looks it's the regex that doesn't work. Could you give me any pointer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/), You can use this annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```